# No Internet connectivity on Ubuntu LTS 16.04

Tags: networking, 16.04, network-manager, internet

I am using Ubuntu LTS 16.04 as a VM on windows 10 but i cannot seem to get any internet connectivity. I cannot ping 8.8.8.8 (network unreachable) and the network manager says 'the system network services are not compatiable with this version.'

For if config i get:
[if config responce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWOOk.png)

For lspci -nnk | grep -e 0200 -e 0280 i get 
[For lspci -nnk | grep -e 0200 -e 0280](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsEdz.png)

For sudo lshw -C network i get 
[sudo lshw -C network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kShU0.png)

and the /etc/network/interfaces file looks like this..
[/etc/network/interfaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4WBg.png)

I have to use this version of Unbuntu as an application i am trying to use will only with with this version so i cannot upgrade.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. how would i add dhcp?

Comment: Look at your VM settings (in the VM host application). What kind of network did you create for the VM? None? Host-Only? NAT? Bridged? Something Else?

Comment: My VM has NAT set

Comment: Desktop? Or headless server (shell only)?

Comment: desktop.. changed to bridged mode and same problem

Comment: Open your Network control panel (Super/Windows Key --> Type "Network"). Look for the Wired section. It should be turned on. Click on the Settings (gear) icon. Details Tab: "Connect automatically" should be checked. IPV4 Tab: "DHCP (Automatic)" should be selected, DNS should be automatic, and Routes should be automatic.

Comment: There is a VirtualBox Host-Only network within my network connections that has DCHP and DNS set to automatic

Comment: "Host-Only" is exactly what it says on the tin: No external access - Guests and Host ONLY. Change it or set up another virtual network. See https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html